# HTTrack possible using cookies

Tags: php, httrack

I want to download the page from a URL, easy enough. But on the first page I have to login, as I normally do from a normal browser. But HTTrack is downloading from the first page since it can't use my cookies or login.

Is it any way for me to get around this?

Answer (score 18):

This question was asked in 2013 so I'm not sure if Httrack was supporting cookies back then but now it definitely does.

Instructions:

1. Login to your website using Firefox or Chrome, then take a look at the login cookie.
2. In the root of the folder where you are downloading your website open the file named `cookies.txt` or if it's not there just create one and open it.
3. Copy the login cookie from your browser to this file.
   (You can also copy every cookies if you don't know which one is the login)

- It might not be required but if you're having problems with your cookies in Httrack, you can try copying your User-Agent from your browser to your Httrack config.
  (I Usually use the User-Agent of my browser, just to be safe.)
- If you don't know how to look at your cookies, it's pretty simple...
  You can use the Developer Tools like so:
  Firefox: `F12 -> Storage -> Cookies`
  Chrome: `F12 -> Application -> Storage -> Cookies`

Example of a cookie.txt for Httrack:
(Make sure to use Tabs in your cookies.txt, spaces don't seem to be working. StackOverflow is automatically converting these Tabs into Spaces.)

```
www.httrack.com TRUE    /       FALSE   1999999999  foo bar
www.example.com TRUE    /folder FALSE   1999999999  JSESSIONID  xxx1234
www.example.com TRUE    /hello  FALSE   1999999999  JSESSIONID  yyy1234
```

Reference: http://httrack.kauler.com/help/Cookies

Comment: Important to note that you must use tabs in the cookies.txt file to separate the values. Spaces do not work.

Comment: I never noticed this before but StackOverflow is converting Tabs characters into Spaces when posting our answers, even for code snippets... Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I found a Chrome plugin which can create this file for you automatically: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/get-cookiestxt-locally/cclelndahbckbenkjhflpdbgdldlbecc

Comment: In my original Answer I included a link to a browser extension that would automatically save the cookie.txt for you, but after a few months this extension got flagged as Malware so I removed it from here. There is probably other extensions like this one that are safe to use but you should always be careful when installing browser extensions, especially with the new ones that don't have many users.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Frank Einstein's answer:

You might not need `cookies.txt`, as httrack also has `--headers` option. So, first copy the relevant session cookie from the brwoser, and then you can use:

```
httrack --headers 'Cookie: SESSIONID=1234...' ...
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using cURL in PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

There are wrappers for this, like:

http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading

Use options such as:

### EDIT: More specific, not tested

Download the class from:

http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading

```
require_once( 'CURL.php' ); //Change this to whatever that class is called in the above
$curl = new CURL();  
$curl->retry = 2;  
    $opts = array(
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20091020 Linux Mint/8 (Helena) Firefox/3.5.3',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE  => 'fb.tmp',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR   => 'fb.tmp',
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 0,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT     => 20
);
$post_data = array(  ); //put your login POST data here
$opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query( $post_data );
$curl->addSession( 'https://www.facebook.com/messages', $opts );  
$result = $curl->exec();  
$curl->clear();
print_r( $result );
```

Note, that sometimes you need to load a page first, to set a cookie, before they will let you login.

Comment: Could you help me some more? with one or more examples?

lets say i want https://www.facebook.com/messages

Comment: Missing ', now added.

Comment: A number of pos. problems? Are the cookies being written to the directory? If not, there is a permissions prob. Also, as mentioned, you often need to first load a page to set a cookie before you login. Use something like HTTP Live Header for FF to see what is going on.

Comment: Httrack is (now) supporting cookies. Look at my answer for more information.